Is Left join the correct action for my combine SFMC SQL
SFMC SQl are already confusing add to that, I'm not confident I'm using the correct action to pull all journey sends, along with who opened, clicks, unsubscribed, and bounces. I'd love you input if I'm doing this write so that I'm not to pulling incorrect record totals:
/* Query to pull Journey Sends,Opens, and clicks 
from Dataview and fields from the source Data Extension
set variables:
j for journey DataView Table
ja for email activity DataView Table
s for Send DataView Table
o for Open DataView Table
c for Click DataView Table
su for all subscriber Table
ea for enterprise attribute Table
jb for job Table
*/

/* display columns from primary table Sends DataView*/
SELECT 
    j.journeyname,
    j.versionnumber,
    ja.activityname AS EmailName,
    ja.JourneyActivityObjectID,
    jb.FromName,
    jb.SendClassification,
    jb.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID,
    s.eventdate AS SendTime,
    s.subscriberkey,
    s.subscriberid AS ContactID,
    s.jobid,
    s.listid,
    s.batchid,
    su.EmailAddress,
    su.subscriberkey AS ContactKey,
    ea.FirstName,
    ea.LastName,
    ea.[Student ID],
    o.EventDate AS OpenEventDate,
    c.LinkName,
    c.LinkContent,
    c.EventDate AS ClickEventDate
FROM 
    _sent s
    
/* left join Opens to Sends to only those records that have opens */    
LEFT JOIN _Open o 
ON s.JobID = o.JobID 
AND s.ListID = o.ListID 
AND s.BatchID = o.BatchID 
AND s.SubscriberID = o.SubscriberID 
AND o.IsUnique = 1
    
/*left join Clicks to Sends to only those records that have Clicks */
LEFT JOIN _Click c 
ON s.JobID = c.JobID 
AND s.ListID = c.ListID 
AND s.BatchID = c.BatchID 
AND s.SubscriberID = c.SubscriberID 
AND c.IsUnique = 1
    
/* Inner join Email Activity Table to sends */      
INNER JOIN 
    _journeyactivity ja
    ON s.triggerersenddefinitionobjectid = ja.journeyactivityobjectid
INNER JOIN 
    _journey j
    ON ja.versionid = j.versionid

/* Inner join All subscribers to sends Table to sends */
INNER JOIN 
    _subscribers su
    ON s.subscriberid = su.subscriberid

/* Left join Enterprise Attributes to get FirstName and LastName */
LEFT JOIN 
    _EnterpriseAttribute ea
    ON s.subscriberid = ea._SubscriberID

/* Left join Job to get FromName */
LEFT JOIN 
    _Job jb
    ON s.JobID = jb.JobID
    
/* Set where clause to only filter for email activities  */    
WHERE 
    ja.activitytype IN ('EMAIL', 'EMAILV2')


If you are experiencing problems with this SQL, it could be due to the combination of left and inner joins. I'm no SQL expert, but I believe you need multiple tables for multiple join types. There are a few options that will work better:

Doing all left joins with the addition of where clauses to handle the exists logic. e.g.,
LEFT JOIN _subscribers su ON s.subscriberid = su.subscriberid
(...)
WHERE
su.SubscriberKey is not null and su.SubscriberKey != ''

Use subqueries to handle the inner joins or to handle the left joins, thus not handling both left and inner joins together. This will be a bit more tricky than option 1.

You could divide the SQL up into two SQLs. One with inner joins i.e., _sent, _journeyacitivity, _journey, and _subscribers. And then one with only left joins, i.e., _sent, _open, _click, _enterpriseattribute, and _job. You would need to update the second SQL, which means you should be aware of which primary keys you choose in your data extension.


Hope this helps
